# Convert Mysql query to Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I need a bit of help... I was trying to convert MySQL query to Codeigniter, but it just not working...

MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    users.email, 
    transactions.id, 
    transactions.type, 
    transactions.status, 
    transactions.sum, 
    transactions.created, 
    transactions.title
FROM 
    transactions, users
where 
    users.id=transactions.user_id and 
    transactions.type='winning_claim' and 
    date(transactions.created)=date(subdate(now(),1))
```

Codeigniter: `

```
$this->db->select('users.email, transactions.id, transactions.type, transactions.status ,transactions.sum, transactions.created, transactions.title');
                $this->db->from('transactions');
                $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = transactions.user_id');
                $this->db->where('transactions.type', 'winning_claim');
                $this->db->where('date(transactions.created)', 'date(subdate(now(), 1))'/*,  FALSE */);
                $select_la_data = $this->db->get();`
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
*You can try this*   
$this->db->select('users.email, transactions.id, transactions.type, 
transactions.status ,transactions.sum, transactions.created, 
transactions.title');  
$this->db->join('transactions','users.id = transactions.user_id');  
$this->db- >get_where
('users',array('transactions.type'=>'winning_claim',
'transactions.created'=>'date(subdate(now(), 1))'))->result_array();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!